# POSTgreSQL 9.5: invalid input syntax for integer when trying to copy from CSV

Tags: postgresql, copy

I've successfully created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tampadocs (
fname varchar(255),
lname varchar(255),
pracName varchar(255),
address varchar(255),
city varchar(255),
state varchar(255),
zip varchar(255),
spec varchar(255),
phone varchar(255),
totalMD integer,
avgPt integer,
mdName varchar(255),
notes varchar(255));
```

Then run the following to import data from a CSV to the table:

```
COPY tampadocs 
FROM 'C:\Users\bam\Desktop\tampadocs.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Total MDs"
CONTEXT:  COPY tampadocs, line 1, column totalmd: "Total MDs"
```

I've looked at each value in the Total MDs column but they are just numbers, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We can't help with the syntax questions if you don't show us what actually is causing that error. Give a sample of the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your file 'tampadocs.csv' has a header line. Can you check on that? The copy syntax you're using is assuming there's only data in the file.

If there's a header line in your file, you can try the following:

```
COPY tampadocs
  FROM 'C:\Users\bam\Desktop\tampadocs.csv'
  WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER);
```

That lets the copy statement know to expect a header line in the file. The full syntax for COPY is available [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: It was the header, thanks a bunch. Next time I will provide more information.